# class function that generates its own objects

Tags: c++

I want to write a class for some use. I want to call a function (say generate) of this class which will generate two objects of this same class.  These two objects will call other function of the class.
Can anyone tell me how to do this?
I want it in C++

```
Class Example{
public:
generate();
other_func();

}

int main()
{
Example generate();
}
```

Now this generate function should create two object of Example and will call other_func();

Comment: I'm not understanding.  Make some pseudo-code or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from your description it would sound very easy:

```
struct Example
{
public:

  static void generate() { Example e1, e2; e1.other_fun(); e2.other_fun(); }
  void other_fun()  { }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [factory methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to generate objects of specified class. Then the created objects based on the business logic processing can invoke other methods.

Answer (score 0):

The only member functions of a class that can be called without an existing member of a class are static member functions. This is a more in depth topic, please see http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/statickeyword.html

So here I create a foo that does what you seem to have asked for and returns the foos:

```
class foo
{
public:
    static void generate()
    {
        foo Temp1;
        foo Temp2;
        Temp1.bar();
        Temp2.bar();
    }

    void bar()
    {

    }
};
```

edit: I removed the return type, per request
edit: I removed the return type completely, and correctly this time. But now I haven't test compiled the code.

Comment: Not only is the Results array unnecessary, doesn't add anything, but you didn't even do it right.  Your Results array is an automatic item and you've called delete[] on it!  Not only that, but you failed to delete the items it contained, which DID need to be.  Gonna have to -1 this.

Comment: I just saw that he didn't want a return type so I quickly removed it. I will fix it again...